# Unable to resolve other hostnames but can ping them (without FQDN)

Tags: networking, dns

I have 2 Ubuntu machines. Host1 is 20.04 LTS, Host2 is 18.04.3 LTS.

Both have no search option configured, however Host2 can actually ping Host1 (without FQDN) even if it's unable to resolve it.

This is for Host1

```
user1@host1:~$ hostname -f
host1.domain.com
user1@host1:~$ dnsdomainname
domain.com
user1@host1:~$ ping host2
ping: host2: Temporary failure in name resolution
user1@host1:~$ ping host2.domain.com
PING host2.domain.com (192.168.23.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from host2.domain.com (192.168.23.102): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.524 ms
```

While for Host2

```
user2@host2:~$ hostname -f
host2.domain.com
user2@host2:~$ dnsdomainname
domain.com
user2@host2:~$ ping host1
PING host1.domain.com (192.168.23.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from host1.domain.com (192.168.23.101): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.315 ms
^C
user2@host2:~$ host host1
Host host1 not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

Host1 is managed by NetworkManager while Host2 is managed by networkd. I don't know which config files to check to figure out why the behaviour is different, and I don't understand how come I can ping an hostname while I'm unable to resolve it.